# Setting unrelated hidden form value from dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set Layers Value to either

GFS meteogram 3day std or
 WRF 20 Global Meteogram 3day Std

based on the selection of the dropdown menu

```
            <div><select id="myselect" class="productViewerParameter" name="MODEL"" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">


        <option value="GFS">GFS</option>
        <option value="WRF 20km Global">WRF</option>

    </select>


<script>                        
function changeHiddenInput(mySelect) {

    var e = document.getElementById("myselect");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    if (strUser == "GFS"){
        var layersInput = document.getElementByName("Layers");
        Layers.value = "GFS Meteogram 3day Std";
} else if (strUser == "WRF") {
        var layersInput = document.getElementByName("Layers");
        Layers.value = "WRF 20 Global Meteogram 3day Std";

}
}
</script>

</div>                      

<div><input type="hidden" name="DURATION" value="3-Day"></div>

<div><input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" name="Layers" value=""></div>
```

Comment: You should make clear what is your question and not only post your code so we have to guess.. Also therese a closing bracket missing in your else if

Comment: In addition... Setting "var e = document.getElementById("my select");" in the function is redundant. You're already passing it in via the "this" reference.

Comment: yeah i can set the var above it with the other two. when i run this Layers.value remains as ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **`updated/working`** code:

**Note:**

1) **`name="MODEL""`** should be **`name="MODEL"`**, you have mistakenly entered two double quotes.

2) You are already getting **`this`**, so you can use **`this`** instead of getting the **`select`** element again.

3) What I am getting is that you are setting **`hiddenInput`** value, so **`Layers.value`** should be the **`layersInput.value`**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="myselect" class="productViewerParameter" name="MODEL" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
            <option value="GFS">GFS</option>
            <option value="WRF 20km Global">WRF</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="DURATION" value="3-Day">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" name="Layers" value="">
    </div>
</body>
<script>                        
function changeHiddenInput(mySelect) {
    var strUser = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
    var layersInput = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
    if (strUser == "GFS"){
        layersInput.value = "GFS Meteogram 3day Std";
    }
    else if (strUser == "WRF") {
        layersInput.value = "WRF 20 Global Meteogram 3day Std";
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```